# Image Slideshow in carousel style on Xamarin.Android with ViewPager and padding with protruding childrens, Viewpages incorrectly calculates arguments

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

Im trying to create an Image Slideshow with ViewPager and padding following this tutorial: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/
Im trying to convert the code on Xamarin.Android code and im stuck on a little detail:

```
var pager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.pager);
pager.SetClipToPadding (false);
pager.PageMargin = 12.ToPixels ();
pager.Adapter = new MyPageAdapter (ChildFragmentManager);

class MyPageAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
public override float GetPageWidth (int position)
{
    return 0.93f;
}

// ...
}
```

Xamarin doesn't have **.ToPixels ()**, what is this ToPixels() does? It is converting dp to pixels?

Moreover i am using ViewPager with padding (for peeking content).

According to javadoc, transformPage function has a "position" argument:
"Position of page relative to the current front-and-center position of the pager. 0 is front and center. 1 is one full page position to the right, and -1 is one page position to the left."

Unfortunately, ViewPager calculates "position" argument incorrectly if ViewPager contains padding.
Im using this Transformer:

```
class WheelPageTransformer : Java.Lang.Object, ViewPager.IPageTransformer
{
private const float MaxAngle = 30F;

public void TransformPage(View view, float position)
{
if (position < -1 || position > 1) 
{
view.Alpha = 0; // The view is offscreen.
} 
else
    {
view.Alpha = 1; 

view.PivotY = view.Height / 2; // The Y Pivot is halfway down the view.

// The X pivots need to be on adjacent sides.
        if (position < 0)
        {
            view.PivotX = view.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            view.PivotX = 0;
        }

        view.RotationY = MaxAngle * position; // Rotate the view.

    }
 }
 }
```

and i think this corrects my problem but i can't convert it for my case https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **ToPixel()** is nothing just an custom made extension method to convert any int value to scale pixel value. Please see the below code snippet:

```
public static class PixelExtensions
{
    public static int ToPixel(this int val)
    {
        float scale = Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
        int pixels = (int)(val * scale + 0.5f);
        return pixels;
    }

    public static int ToSizeUnit(ComplexUnitType toUnit, int value)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(TypedValue.ApplyDimension(toUnit, value, Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics));
    }
}
```

It has two method one **ToPixel()** is an extension method that help you to convert any int value as pixel. Other one **ToSizeUnit()** is kinda of generic you can use for any expected or available size unit.

1. ToPixel()

   ```
   viewPager.PageMargin = 12.ToPixel();
   ```
2. ToSizeUnit()

   ```
   viewPager.PageMargin = PixelExtensions.ToSizeUnit(ComplexUnitType.Px,12);
   //It can be ComplexUnitType.Dip or more :)
   ```

**EDIT:** Update answer for second issue which is conversion code.

Your provided link code conversion looks like this below:

```
 public abstract class FixedPageTransformer : ViewPager.IPageTransformer
 {
    ViewPager mPager;
    int mClientWidth, mPaddingLeft;
    public FixedPageTransformer(ViewPager pager)
    {
        this.mPager = pager;
        mClientWidth = mPager.MeasuredWidth - mPager.PaddingLeft - mPager.PaddingRight;
        mPaddingLeft = mPager.PaddingLeft;
    }
    public void TransformPage(View view, float v)
    {
        FixedTransformPage(view, (float)(view.Left - (mPager.ScrollX + mPaddingLeft)) / mClientWidth);
    }

    public abstract void FixedTransformPage(View view, float fixedVal);
 }

public class WheelPageTransformer : FixedPageTransformer
{
    public WheelPageTransformer(ViewPager yourViewPager):base(yourViewPager)
    {

    }

    public override void FixedTransformPage(View view, float fixedVal)
    {
        int pageWidth = view.Width;

        ViewPager parent = (ViewPager)view.Parent;
        fixedVal -= parent.PaddingRight / (float)pageWidth;

        //Your transformation with the new position.
    }
}
```

Cheers!!

RIYAZ

Comment: thanks about that. Can you help me on the 2nd part of my problem?transformation gets position wrong because of the padding, i have post a possible solution in java but i cant convert it

Comment: Sure, What issue you are facing while conversion?

Comment: i have update my questions with more details about the 2nd issue, sorry it wasn't clear before, viewpager calculate position wrong when you use padding. i have explain with images the problem also here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/51226/image-viewer-slider-in-carousel-style#latest and here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64046 is a possible solution in java that i must convert it to use it in my WheelPageTransformer, i have try but i can't convert it. Thanks

Comment: wow your fast :) in order to understand what we have do: every transformation has FixedTransformPage function and with this code we override the default functionality?

Comment: Thanks :)  In order to use It's functionality you will override  FixedTransformPage() method and assign fixedVal to your pager as per the view.

Comment: im putting your code on a class with also my transformation code and i get  Error CS1729: 'FixedPageTransformer' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments (CS1729)

Comment: Of course you must pass ViewPager instance to its constructor because It has a constructor with one parameter see:

 public FixedPageTransformer(ViewPager pager)
    {
        this.mPager = pager;
        mClientWidth = mPager.MeasuredWidth - mPager.PaddingLeft - mPager.PaddingRight;
        mPaddingLeft = mPager.PaddingLeft;
    }

Comment: im getting the error on the Transformer class not when im assigning the transformer to the viewpager

Comment: Which is Transformer class? I have'n write a code for this. is it your side?

Comment: Ohh Sorry, I have updated the code constructor was missing.

Comment: i have try to create it also but i was missing this :base(yourViewPager) :)

Comment: the image still doesnt appear exactly on the center, it's about 1 inch right. but i think i will figure it out why. Why is so hard to add padding and transformation on ViewPager? :D

Answer (score 0):

The correct FixedPageTransformer Class that work for me was:

```
public abstract class FixedPageTransformer : Java.Lang.Object, ViewPager.IPageTransformer
{
    ViewPager mPager;
    int mClientWidth, mPaddingLeft;
    public FixedPageTransformer(ViewPager pager)
    {
        this.mPager = pager;
        mClientWidth = mPager.Width - mPager.PaddingLeft - mPager.PaddingRight;
        mPaddingLeft = mPager.PaddingLeft / 2;
    }
    public void TransformPage(View view, float v)
    {
        FixedTransformPage(view, (float)(view.Left - (mPager.ScrollX + mPaddingLeft)) / mClientWidth);
    }

    public abstract void FixedTransformPage(View view, float fixedVal);
}

public class WheelPageTransformer : FixedPageTransformer
{
    public WheelPageTransformer(ViewPager yourViewPager):base(yourViewPager)     { }

    public override void FixedTransformPage(View view, float fixedVal)
    {
        int pageWidth = view.Width;

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)view.Parent;
        fixedVal -= (parent.PaddingRight / 2) / (float)pageWidth;

        //Your transformation with the new position.
        const float MaxAngle = 30F;

        if (fixedVal < -1 || fixedVal > 1) {
            view.Alpha = 0; // The view is offscreen.
        } else {
            view.Alpha = 1; 

            view.PivotY = view.Height / 2; // The Y Pivot is halfway down the view.

            // The X pivots need to be on adjacent sides.
            if (fixedVal < 0) {
                view.PivotX = view.Width;
            } else {
                view.PivotX = 0;
            }

            view.RotationY = MaxAngle * fixedVal; // Rotate the view.

        }
    }

}
```

I haven't add margin and i haven't override pageWidth.